# Unique Cartesian product from one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "verb" in my database where the only attribute is "word".  The initial task was to create a list comparing each entry to the rest.  I accomplished this by entering the command:

```
select * from verb as word cross join verb;
```

Now I want to modify the query so that it removes duplicates and only shows the first 10 results.  I'm stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select v1.word as word1, v2.word as word2
from verb v1 join
     verb v2
     on v1.word < v2.word
limit 10;
```

(If you want the two words to appear twice, then use `<>` rather than `<`.)

This limits the results to 10 rows.  There is no concept of "first" with SQL tables unless you use `order by`.  You haven't specified the ordering, so this is just 10 rows that the database decides to return to you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Clear as day now :)